# Why isn't ember using the correct host for REST requests?

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js

I'm trying to get a simple REST API setup going with ember, but I can't get it to hit the correct end point, I've tried all sorts with no avail, but my code currently looks like this:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://myserver.com'
});

/* Setup routes */

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("bar");
});

App.BarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('bar');
    }
});
```

In the main index template I have `{{#link-to "bar"}}Bars{{/link-to}}`, yet when I click the link (running the page locally) I see this in the console:

```
OPTIONS file://localhost/bars
```

Whatever I try it's always using a relative URL and not prefixing the host as I'm expecting, and if I put a breakpoint in ember_data.js on the line `Ember.$.ajax(hash);` I can see that `hash.url` is just "/bars". What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure about your link-to part. link-to redirects you to the link according to your Router.map. this.route("bar"); is short version of this.route("bar", {path: "/bar"}); it is independent of RESTAdapter.

Comment: The options method is executed when you perform a preflight request. Are you changing some headers in the server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont forget to set the **Adapter** to the **Store**, like this:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://www.yourdomain.com',
    namespace: 'url/path/to/app'
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: App.Adapter
});
```

Hope it helps

This answer worked for me after upgrading ember-data to version 1.0.0-beta2. At some stage in following the guide I ended up with an older release and there have been breaking changes since then.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to run your Ember app from your local filesystem?  file:///...  To get remote AJAX calls to work you need to be accessing your app via http (or https) using a local server of some sort.

Comment: Even accessing it via Apache gives the same result :(

Comment: Yeah it's doing the same for me

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to set some data model and then connect adapter for this model.

```
App.BarAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host:'http://myserver.com',
});

App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
  author: DS.attr('string'),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned that I have the model there too!